# PHP - continue; está saliendo de la foreach loop, no de la iteración

Tags: php

Estoy trabajando en un script PHP y `continue;` está saliendo de todas las iteraciones de `foreach`, en vez de saltarse de la iteración actual a la siguiente:

Método:

```
public function validateInputsLength() {
foreach(get_object_vars($this) as $key => $value) {
if($key == 'db' or 'mcpe_list') continue;
if(strlen($value) < constant('self::MIN_' . strtoupper($key) . '_LENGTH')) {
return ['result' => ['success' => false, 'type' => 'MIN_LENGTH', 'var' => $key]];
} elseif(strlen($value) > constant('self::MAX_' . strtoupper($key) . '_LENGTH')) {
return ['result' => ['success' => false, 'type' => 'MAX_LENGTH', 'var' => $key]];
} else {
return ['result' => ['success' => true]];
}
}
}
```

Código que utilizo para llamar la función:

```
if($api->validateInputsLength()['result']['success'] ===! true) {
if($api->validateInputsLength()['result']['type'] == 'MIN_LENGTH') {
$api->sendResponse('ERR_ARG_' . strtoupper($api->validateInputsLength()['result']['var']) . '_TOO_SHORT');
} elseif($api->validateInputsLength()['result']['type'] == 'MAX_LENGTH') {
$api->sendResponse('ERR_ARG_' . strtoupper($api->validateInputsLength()['result']['var']) . '_TOO_LONG');
}
}
```

Gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: En principio, el if no parece estar correcto: `if($key == 'db' or 'mcpe_list') continue;` el `or` compara nada con `mcpe_list`. Debería ser: `if($key == 'db' || $key == 'mcpe_list') continue;`

Comment: @A.Cedano Ok, pero el problema persiste.

Comment: Por algún motivo, no me fío nunca de esa forma de usar `if` sin llaves de apertura `{`  y de cierre `}`. ¿Qué pasa si lo pones así: `if($key == 'db' || $key== 'mcpe_list') {echo "Ha entrado aquí"; continue;}` De todos modos, ¿cómo sabes que realmente está saliendo?, puede que sea cuestión de que las condiciones no se están cumpliendo o de que no haya datos que mostrar. Puedes depurar poniendo un `echo` en cada posibilidad para verificar.

Answer (score 0):

Para confirmar mis sospechas, hice una prueba basada en datos ficticios, ya que para mí es imposible evaluar tus datos.

La prueba reveló que en efecto, el uso del if donde tienes el `continue` sin las llaves, no pasa de ahí.

Si ponemos las llaves, el código funciona.

Como dije, son datos fiticios. Si a ti no te funciona, poniéndolo de esta manera, ya sería cuestión de los datos, no del `continue`.

Por cierto, esos `return` del código me parecen también algo extraños.

#### `Código:` [`Ver Demo`](http://rextester.com/NVCTO15766):

```
<?php 


validateInputsLength();

function validateInputsLength() 
{
    $arrTest=array("db"=>"1", "mcpe_list"=>"2", "mcpe_list2"=>"2", "mcpe_list9"=>"99999999");
    $constant1=5;
    foreach($arrTest as $key => $value) 
    {
        if($key == 'db' || $key=='mcpe_list') 
        {
            echo "Entró aquí\n"; 
            continue;
        }

        if(strlen($value) < $constant1) 

        {
            echo "Se cumple esto****: ['result' => ['success' => false, 'type' => 'MIN_LENGTH', 'var' => $key]]\n";
            //return ['result' => ['success' => false, 'type' => 'MIN_LENGTH', 'var' => $key]];

        } elseif(strlen($value) > $constant1) {

            echo "Se cumple esto****: result' => ['success' => false, 'type' => 'MAX_LENGTH', 'var' => $key]]\n";
            //return ['result' => ['success' => false, 'type' => 'MAX_LENGTH', 'var' => $key]];

        } else {

            echo "Se cumple esto****: ['result' => ['success' => true]]\n";
            //return ['result' => ['success' => true]];

        }
    }
}

?>
```

---

#### `Resultado:`

```
Entró aquí
Entró aquí
Se cumple esto****: ['result' => ['success' => false, 'type' => 'MIN_LENGTH', 'var' => mcpe_list2]]
Se cumple esto****: ['result' => ['success' => false, 'type' => 'MAX_LENGTH', 'var' => mcpe_list9]]
```